# Python eel module doesn`t recognize JS functions

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

when Im calling the JS function through my python code with the eel.function()() it says "Cannot find reference 'function' in '**init**.py'", it seems to be working fine in my teachers video.
Here`s the python code:

```
eel.init('web')


def user_input():
    eel.get_ready()()

    while True:
        loading = int(input("[+] start loading? 1/0"))
        if loading == 1:
            eel.js_start_loading()()

        elif loading == 0:
            eel.js_stop_loading()()


eel.spawn(user_input())
eel.start('index.html', size=(850, 360), port=0)
```

Here`s the JS code:

```
    var progress = null;
    eel.expose(js_start_loading);
    function js_start_loading() {
        progress = Metro.activity.open({
            type: 'square',
            overlayColor: '#fff',
            overlayAlpha: 1,
            text: '<div class=\'mt-2 text-small\'>Please, wait...</div>
        });
    }

    eel.expose(js_stop_loading);
    function js_stop_loading() {
        Metro.activity.close(progress);
    }

   eel.expose(get_ready);
   function get_ready() {
       $(document).ready(function(){
           return true;
       });
   }
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Shouldn't it be `eel.spawn(user_input)`?

Comment: yea my bad, but still the python code doesnt work, like, it is opening the html window but then nothing

Comment: Are you able to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The code provided thus far isn't a complete example (missing index.html, JS references 'Metro' which isn't defined, etc.). It's difficult to help out without being able to reproduce the exact error and investigate.

Comment: This code fragment is not enough to learn and reproduce